# How to get this to stop at 20

Tags: python

I would like for this to stop at 20. By which I mean, when it asks you to input another number it should stop after the 20th time. 
Currently I have an accumulating counter that when it reaches 20 it prints the "Enter one more number". It does this at the 20th time, but afterwards it keeps going with asking you to input more numbers. I would like it to stop asking for input after the 20th time.
Thanks. This is apart of a larger homework problem.

```
def main ():
    print()
    print("Finds the lowest, highest, average, and total to 20 numbers.")
    print()
    number, count, numberlist = getnumber()
    print("Stop.")


def getnumber ():
    count = 0
    numberlist = []
    for count in range(20):
        count = count + 1
        number = float(input("Please enter another number : "))
        numberlist.append(number)
    while count != 20:
        number = float(input("Please enter one more number : "))
        numberlist.append(number)

return number, count   

main()
```

Comment: Why is that while loop there?

Comment: read https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop, understand how a for loop works, and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as follows:

```
def get_numbers(count=20):
    numbers = []
    numbers.append(float(input("Please enter a number : "))) # first
    for _ in range(count-2):
        numbers.append(float(input("Please enter another number : "))) # next 18
    numbers.append(float(input("Please enter one more number : "))) # last
    return numbers
```

Note that with a `for` loop you don't need to manually increment the loop counter. Also, there is no need to `return count`; you already know how many there will be.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that you are not changing value of `count` inside `while` loop - that is why it never stops. After `for` is executed `count` is exactly 19 and never reaches 20 after that.

Second of all, you do not need `while` at all - `for` loop will work for 20 iterations and stop

```
def getnumber ():
    count = 0
    numberlist = []
    for count in range(20):
        count = count + 1
        number = float(input("Please enter another number : "))
        numberlist.append(number)

    return number, count, numberlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option (your approach extended)

```
limit = 5

def main ():
    print("Finds the lowest, highest, average, and total to {} numbers.".format(limit))
    numbs = getnumber()
    print(numbs)
    print("lowest:", min(numbs))
    print("highest:", max(numbs))
    print("avg:", sum(numbs)/len(numbs))
    print("total:", sum(numbs))
    print("Stop.")

def getnumber ():
    numberlist = []
    for count in range(limit):
        if count == limit-1:
            number = float(input("Please enter one more number : "))
            numberlist.append(number)
        else:
            number = float(input("Please enter another number : "))
            numberlist.append(number)
    return numberlist

main()
```

Output

```
Finds the lowest, highest, average, and total to 5 numbers.
[6.0, 3.0, 8.0, 4.0, 2.0]
('lowest:', 2.0)
('highest:', 8.0)
('avg:', 4.6)
('total:', 23.0)
Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with the code you posted. First of you should indent the return statement so it is part of getnumber. Secondly you return two values but unpack three values in main. If I fix those two things the code works. The reason that count is 20 after the for loop is that you declare count outside the loop, so on each iteration count will be set to the next integer and then incremented once more by

```
count = count + 1
```

If you did not have the extra increment inside the loop, count would be 19 after the for loop terminates because range(N) does not include N.

And you can rewrite the code with a list comprehension to get a very concise version

```
def getnumber(prompt, n):
    return [float(input(prompt)) for _ in range(n)]
```

This will give you a list of the numbers.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer this to `[float(input(prompt)) for _ in range(n)]`? Creating a list of `prompt`s seems unnecessary.

Comment: It only put it there so someone could improve it ;-). I will change it